How can I use an ultra-wide Dell monitor with a MacBook Pro?
I have a 2020 MacBook Pro running Monterey 12.6, with four Thunderbolt 3 ports. I recently upgraded from a 20" external monitor to an ultra-wide 34" Dell 3422DWG and find that I cannot configure the monitor to work correctly -- either the display is stretched out horizontally (for example, pulling up an image of a circle shows an oval) or it only uses the center third of the monitor. (Notably, when I shared my desktop on Zoom the viewer said it looked perfectly normal to them, and the circle was a true circle.)
Hardware is:
2020 MacBook Pro with four Thunderbolt ports, one connected to a
SMKLink vp6920 multiport (USB A, HDMI, USB C, two card readers ) adapter, reported by the system as
 - Product ID: 0x5411
 - Vendor ID: 0x0bda (Realtek Semiconductor Corp.)
 - Version: 1.04
 - Speed: up to 480 Mb/s

I used the HDMI cable that came with the monitor to plug into the HDMI port on the hub.
I searched extensively and only found other people complaining of similar things, including someone complaining that their working setup started stretching after an upgrade to Monterey.
Two questions that did not lead to my solution, but may lead other people to their solutions:
Dell in2020m widescreen monitor and a MacBook Pro (2012, 16:9 aspect ratio)
Connect Macbook Pro Late 2016 with monitor DELL UP2516D (2016, best answer recommended HDMI multi-port dongle)

Can people downvoting explain why?  I searched for this information all over the place, found lots of people complaining about the same thing, took a shot in the dark, and solved the problem.  I'd think that would be a perfect topic for a Q&A.

The solution that worked beautifully for me was buying a USB C to DisplayPort adapter (readily available online for about US$20) and plugging in the DisplayPort cable that came with the monitor.

DisplayPort 1.4
32.4 Gbps
8K@60Hz

I can now use the monitor as my primary or secondary display at default resolution of 3440x1440 (60Hz or even higher, all the way up to 144 Hz), without clipping or smearing.
There may have been other solutions possible using newer HDMI protocols, a dedicated Thunderbolt to HDMI adapter or cable, or simply buying a better/newer hub, but I tried this one thing and it worked.
I assume the takeaway is that you need higher data throughput to drive an oversized monitor.
(Casting further blame on the hub, I plugged the monitor's stock HDMI cable directly into the HDMI port of a mid-2014 MacBook Pro Retina running MacOS Mojave 10.14.6 and it auto-detected and worked perfectly with no configuration needed at all, though the system felt sluggish.)

Plugging into your mid-2014 MBP would have felt sluggish because the display is using your GPU (whether it be discrete or integrated) quite resource intensively and I believe the maximum refresh rate is 60Hz for MacBooks back in 2014.
